# photo from library will not move and scale

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app the user is able to select a photo from the library with the code below. Because I want the user to crop the photo I have made sure that setAllowsEditing:YES.

When you select the photo you can move and scale the image but when the image is viewed later on (selectedImage) the image reverts back to its original size ???

```
    myPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [myPicker setSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [myPicker setToolbarHidden:NO];
    [myPicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
     myPicker.delegate = self;

    //this adds mypicker to current view
    [self presentViewController:myPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
selectedImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];

selectedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to use "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage" instead of "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage".

thanks.